# Make Google Map focus follow specific locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple locations pulled from DB ordered chronologically - I put the locations into the map and make a polyline connecting them.

I would like to know how to do the following: I want to put a "Play button" somewhere on the page which eventually starts moving the focus of the Map window along the edges of the polyline from the oldest location to the latest one. The best option would be if the transition is sequential (not jumping from one location to the other).

I don't have much of experience with Google Maps API, but I suppose this is really easy to do. (with `setTimeout` maybe?)

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html, instead of moving the marker, move the map center.

Comment: Actually [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html) might be more what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, the second one looks like something I was looking for! If you make this an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example of animating a marker along a polyline is:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html

Code ported from [Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/).

```
//=============== animation functions ======================
      function updatePoly(d) {
        // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

        if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
           if (poly2.getPath().getLength()>1) {
             poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength()-1)
           }
           poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
        } else {
          poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.getPath().getAt(polyline.getPath().getLength()-1));
        }
      }


      function animate(d) {
        if (d>eol) {
          var endlocation = polyline.getPath().getAt(polyline.getPath().getLength()-1);
          map.panTo(endlocation);
          marker.setPosition(endlocation);
          return;
        }
        var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
        map.panTo(p);
        marker.setPosition(p);
        updatePoly(d);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
      }


function startAnimation() {
        if (timerHandle) clearInterval(timerHandle);
        eol=polyline.Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
        if (marker) { 
           marker.setMap(null);
           delete marker;
           marker = null;
        }
        if (!marker) marker = new google.maps.Marker({location:polyline.getPath().getAt(0), map:map} /* ,{icon:car} */);
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:10});
        setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}


//=============== ~animation functions =====================
```