# How to get Lat Long of moving object on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on Google maps, and in my map I have build a moving object using [Animating Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate) article

my question is that I want to get the location of moving object (animating symbol).

like a symbol is moving between point A to B so I wants to know on each timeticks its location.

```
function animateCircle() {
    var count = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
      count = (count + 1) % 200;

      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
      line.set('icons', icons);

      GetLatLongAtThisPosition(); // i wants to get the current location of here each time          

  }, 20);
}
```

Comment: Why has someone voted to close this as being _"This question does not appear to be about programming"_ ?  Seems pretty on-topic to me

Comment: @duncan, not me, but is flagged as: **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example** i guess voter wants a fiddle or some MCV example

Comment: The user isn't asking for debugging help or demonstrating broken code, they want to know how to achieve some new functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol doesn't have a position, but you can calculate it:

```
var position = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(lineCoordinates[0], lineCoordinates[1], (count / 200));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48qjjzro/1/)

```
function animateCircle() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var count = 0;
  window.setInterval(function () {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;

    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
    var position = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(lineCoordinates[0], lineCoordinates[1], (count / 200));
    if (!marker) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(position);
    }
    infowindow.setContent(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
  }, 20);
}
```

code snippet:

```js
// This example adds an animated symbol to a polyline.

var line;
var marker;
var lineCoordinates;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.291, 153.027),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  lineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(22.291, 153.027),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.291, 153.027)
  ];

  // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
  // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: '#393'
  };

  // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: lineCoordinates,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });

  animateCircle();
}

// Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
// at fixed intervals.
function animateCircle() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var count = 0;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;

    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
    var position = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(lineCoordinates[0], lineCoordinates[1], (count / 200));
    if (!marker) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
      });
      infowindow.setContent(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    } else {
      marker.setPosition(position);
    }
    infowindow.setContent(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
  }, 20);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: The original question was about a single point along a line with two vertices. That would be another question.  Or you could look at similar questions about animating a marker along a polyline (like this one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200121/make-google-map-focus-follow-specific-locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200121/make-google-map-focus-follow-specific-locations).

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately i don't think you can get Lat Long of a SymbolPath with the Google Maps API.

If you `console.log` the `icons[0]` you will see that the `icon` `object` only have **path**, **scale** and **strokeColor**:

```
console.log(icons[0].icon)

{ 
  path: 0, 
  scale: 8, 
  strokeColor: "#393"
}
```