# Retrieving the position of polyline icons on a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a polyline in a google map with icons being repeated at every 25 % of the line, as follows:

```
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: myTrip,
    icons: [{
        icon: lineSymbol,
        offset: '100%',
        repeat: '25%'
    },
        {
            icon: lineSymbol1,
            offset: '100%',
            repeat: '25%'
        }],
    strokeColor: getRandomColor(),
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3
 });
```

Now, what I want is to get the longitude and latitude (coordinate) of the lineSymbol and lineSymbol1 icons placed on the polyline. I cannot figure out or find how to get the position of such icons. Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Lat Long of moving object on google maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303937/how-to-get-lat-long-of-moving-object-on-google-maps)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.