# How to add info window on moving marker in Google maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm creating a project in which I want to add info window to moving markers in Google map API.
[I have added info window as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB6RB.png)
but I'm not able to add the same on ships.

Code for marker on line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
    icons: [
    {
      icon: symbolShape,
      offset: '0%'
    }
    ],
    strokeColor: Colors[i],
    strokeOpacity: 0.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
  lineArray[i] = line;

  google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,line);
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
  line1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
    icons: [
    {
      icon: symbolSource,
      offset: '0%'
    }, {
      icon: symbolDestination,
      offset: '100%'
    }
    ],
    strokeColor: Colors[i],
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
  lineArray1[i] = line1;
}

console.log(lineArray.length);
console.log(lineArray1.length);

  //Map boundaries
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(line.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

The entire code is at 
[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2x4w5bms/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  What is `DrivePath`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Lat Long of moving object on google maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303937/how-to-get-lat-long-of-moving-object-on-google-maps)

Comment: Made required changes in JSFiddle code. @geocodezip